# Wrong X axis label on hover

Tags: javascript, charts

[image]

[image]

as you can see from the picture above, the hover label don't match on the X label below it. Here is my ChartJS code:

```
        labelsx = Array();
        for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            hours = i;
            labelsx[labelsx.length] = hours + ":00";
        }
                buyerdata = [];
                traderdata = [];
                var c_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                for (var i = 0; i < c_data["chart_buyers"].length; i++) {
                        buyerdata[buyerdata.length] = {x : c_data["chart_buyers"][i]["HourNumber"] + ":00", y: c_data["chart_buyers"][i]["Buyers"]}
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < c_data["chart_traders"].length; i++) {
                        traderdata[traderdata.length] = {x : c_data["chart_traders"][i]["HourNumber"] + ":00", y: c_data["chart_traders"][i]["TotalTraders"]}
                    }

                var config = {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labelsx,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Buyers',
                        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.fillgreen,
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
                        data: buyerdata,
                        fill: true
                    }, {
                        label: 'Traders',
                        fill: true,
                        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.fillblue,
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                        data: traderdata
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: false,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Buyers/Traders'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false,
                    },
                    hover: {
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        intersect: true
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Time'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Number of Buyers/Traders'
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            };
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

as you can see, i defined the labels for the default x values and on the datasets i defined both x and y on the for loop. the data matched on the X label where the points are supposed to be but hovering on the points results in a tooltip that don't match the X label below that point. What's the fix for this problem?

here is the example data of `c_data["chart_traders"]` and `c_data["chart_buyers"]`

```
{
    "chart_buyers": [
        {
            "HourNumber": "1",
            "Buyers": "84"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "2",
            "Buyers": "57"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "3",
            "Buyers": "36"
        }
    ],
    "chart_traders": [
        {
            "HourNumber": "1",
            "TotalTraders": "18"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "2",
            "TotalTraders": "15"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "3",
            "TotalTraders": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i already edited the question. i added the c_data contents on the question. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the elements in the `labels` array should align with the elements in the `datasets.data` arrays

in other words, the first element in `datasets.data` will be assigned to the first element in `labels`

in this case,
the first element in `labelsx` = `"0:00"`
the first element in `buyerdata` = `{"x":"1:00","y":"84"}`

there are a few ways you can fix this...

**1)** start the labels at `1`, since there doesn't appear to be any data for `0`

```
for (i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
    var hours = i;
    labelsx[labelsx.length] = hours + ":00";
}
```

**2)** reduce `HourNumber` number by `1`

```
buyerdata[buyerdata.length] = {x : c_data["chart_buyers"][i]["HourNumber"] - 1 + ":00", y: c_data["chart_buyers"][i]["Buyers"]}
```

**3)** if there truly isn't any data for `0:00`, begin with a `null` entry in the data arrays

```
buyerdata = [null];
traderdata = [null];
```

see following working snippet using option **3)**...

```js
var labelsx = Array();
for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    var hours = i;
    labelsx[labelsx.length] = hours + ":00";
}

var c_data = {
    "chart_buyers": [
        {
            "HourNumber": "1",
            "Buyers": "84"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "2",
            "Buyers": "57"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "3",
            "Buyers": "36"
        }
    ],
    "chart_traders": [
        {
            "HourNumber": "1",
            "TotalTraders": "18"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "2",
            "TotalTraders": "15"
        },
        {
            "HourNumber": "3",
            "TotalTraders": "23"
        }
    ]
};

buyerdata = [null];
traderdata = [null];
for (var i = 0; i < c_data["chart_buyers"].length; i++) {
    buyerdata[buyerdata.length] = {x : c_data["chart_buyers"][i]["HourNumber"] + ":00", y: c_data["chart_buyers"][i]["Buyers"]}
}

for (var i = 0; i < c_data["chart_traders"].length; i++) {
    traderdata[traderdata.length] = {x : c_data["chart_traders"][i]["HourNumber"] + ":00", y: c_data["chart_traders"][i]["TotalTraders"]}
}

var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labelsx,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Buyers',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,1)',
            data: buyerdata,
            fill: true
        }, {
            label: 'Traders',
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)',
            data: traderdata
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Buyers/Traders'
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Time'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Number of Buyers/Traders'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>
```